# Login not working in Spring Boot (with Spring Security) when hosted to server

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, digital-ocean

I have created a Spring Boot app, using **Spring security** and **H2 database**. The application is working fine in **Local** and **Heroku**. But, not working in Ubuntu Droplet of Digital Ocean. When I am hitting the server it comes up with the login page. But when I am tying to login with credentials (kept in h2 database) it is loading the page forever and not coming with any response. I am able to access other urls which are not secured. I am using **j_spring_security_check** for authentication.

Things that I have checked:

- H2 dependency is added in compile time (Removed
  runtime).
- schema.sql and data.sql is getting executed (Can be seen in startup
  log)

Comment: Please provide the error you see when you hit F12 in the browser.

Comment: It doesn't give any error. It loads the page for ever. (Spinning icon in the tab)

Answer (score 0):

The following solved the issue:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-additional-entropy-for-cloud-servers-using-haveged.

It was hanging due to less entropy in the server and this can hang at any point specially when a cryptographic logic is running.

> - Web Server
> - Incoming/Outgoing Mail Server
> - SSH/SFTP
>
> Should any of these daemons require randomness when all available entropy has been exhausted, **they may pause to wait for more, which can cause excessive delays in your application**. Even worse, since most modern applications will either resort to using its own random seed created at program initialization, or to using /dev/urandom to avoid blocking, your applications will suffer from lower quality random data.